# Type hinting is broken for non consuming iterator over `Vec`

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

In my VSCode IDE (rust + rust-analyzer),

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
for x in v.iter() {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

the above codes can't show Auto-Type Hints correctly (while most other hints work well), but several weeks ago they did. The problems are:

1. `let v = vec![1, 2, 3];` Type hinting doesn't work for `v`. When the mouse is moved upon `v`, it shows `let v: {unknown}`

[image]

2. `v.iter()` I can't find the method `iter()` in the autocomplete list after typing `v.` However, `into_iter()` exists in the list.

[image]

3. `for x in v.iter()` Type hinting doesn't work for `x`, even if I explicitly announce `v : Vec<u8> = vec![1,2,3];` Therefore, I can't use the auto-hinted methods for `x`.

How to fix these problems?

Versions I used are the latest (by 2022-05-17):

> code : 1.67.1-1651841865

> rust : nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.63.0-nightly (4c5f6e627 2022-05-17)

> rust-analyzer : v0.3.1059

Comment: Does using `vec![1i32, 2, 3]` solve your problem?

Comment: type inference where? I guess you mean type hinting in your editor...?

Comment: no, the problem is still the same after adding `_i32`. @hkBst

Comment: Yes this is what I really mean. I will correct the statement. @Netwave

Comment: What version of each piece of software are you running?

Comment: I am using the latest rust-analyzer(v0.2.867) and rust (nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu). In fact, I have upgraded them for many times in the past hour. @hkBst

Comment: Are you sure that's the latest rust-analyzer version? Mine is `v0.3.1059`

Comment: sorry, it's `v0.3.1059` indeed. @IanS.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think the problem is solved, after I re-installed the vscode-extension `Rust`. It is strange that although the `Rust` extension finally became dark and inactive again, the re-installation process seemed to let the vscode GUI be deeply refreshed and flashed. And after that, type hinting and autocomplete both come back correctly.

Comment: I thought you weren't supposed to use the Rust extension (`rust-lang.rust`) at all if you have rust-analyzer (`rust-lang.rust-analyzer`) installed?

Comment: Yes, I have `rust-analyzer` installed. However, no matter what I did to it (disable/uninstall/install), type hinting and autocomplete still remained incomplete. So I gave up and turned to `Rust` extension instead for a try. Then the installation of `Rust` extension terminated with reason that I already had the up-to-date `rust-analyzer` installed, but surprisingly, with several times of IDE flashing and screen refreshing, type hinting and autocomplete became normal and complete. @BallpointBen